# Expand li element to fit content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the parent li (menu item) to widen (horizontally) on hover to fit all of the ul li items (submenu items) without hardcoding a width so no text is floating or cut off.

I am making a menu using an unordered list.  Each submenu item is within the li tags of the main menu.  My menu is horizontal and shows the submenu items when you hover over the elements.

I have tried various ways to try and get the li element to expand to the size of the submenu items or stay the same size if they are smaller.  My clunky but working way was to hardcode a width of 22% on hover.  I was wondering if there was a way to do this and to nicely fit the text rather than have a lot of white space.  Hardcoding the width also causes menu items without submenu items to expand (I could work around this but I don't want to hardcode it to begin with).

I need to do this entirely in vanilla html, css, and javascript.  It would also be nice if the solution were cross-browser compatible.

I apologize if my code is non-conventional, I have been trying to teach myself css.  Thank you in advance.

The following is an example of my HTML/CSS (minus the links):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  font-family: Gotham Book, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbaritems {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navbaritems ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
}
#navbaritems ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
#navbaritems ul li ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6vh;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
#navbaritems ul li ul li {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
}
#navbaritems ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#navbaritems ul li:hover {
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 22%;
}
#navbaritems ul li ul li:hover {
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 100%;
}
#navbaritems ul li a {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 1vw;
  display: block;
  height: 4vh;
  line-height: 4vh;
  color: #808080;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#navbaritems ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #82c986;
  color: #ffffff;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
#navbaritems ul li a.active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="addBottomShadow">
  <div id="navbaritems">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Patient Eligibility</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Eligibility Tracker</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Claim Status</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Remittance Advice</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>E-Claims Batch Status</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Fees</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Update Fees</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Reimbursement Report</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Reimbursement Detail Report</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Submit Fees</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Inquiries</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Customer Service Inquiries</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>COB Change Requests</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Submit Inquiry</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Settings</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Procedure Sets</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Eligibility Tracker</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Claim Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Remittance Advice</a>
          </li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Other</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Provider Seminars</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is efficient solution or not. but you could assign ids to largest ul li items in each main li item. And assign its width to main li item in JS.

Comment: The html is generated dynamically from a database table so I am reluctant to hardcode anything.  I'm hoping there's some sort of CSS bit that I missed or could change to accomplish this.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is the number of main navbar items going to shrink or grow? Right now you have nine items ("home", "patient eligibility," etc.) Does your situation need to account for their being, say, eight items? Is screen resolution a major consideration?

Comment: Screen resolution is not a major consideration, the font-size is also set to 1vw so I don't think it really matters.  I've tested this menu on really small screens already and it's never been a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem here is that the parent `li` element only knows to be as big as the main `a` until hover because the child `ul` has `display:none;` which means the width is effectively 0.  Instead of using `display:none;` you could try forcing the height to be 0 and leaving the initial width. Then on hover, do `height:inherit;` to display the menu items.  Remember to use `overflow:hidden;` so things don't go outside of the element when the height isn't big enough for them.

EDIT: Needed to do some more work, but [I think this](http://codepen.io/fauxserious/pen/VeKeZw) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I might have worded it poorly, but the width is the problem because each submenu item defaults to the size of the parent li.  I want the whole parent li to expand on hover so all the submenu items can fit.   Thanks anyway.

Comment: According to the code snippet, the width is only as big as the anchor tag (not as big as the biggest item in the submenu, because it's display is none).

Comment: I tried your method, it doesn't seem to be working.  The submenu still has the same width as the parent li.  It also makes it display the submenu a little to the right of the parent li.

Comment: Check the pen I've added.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood again, I'm trying to keep it the width of the menu item, but on hover make it widen so to the size of the biggest submenu item.

Comment: So do the same thing with width that I did with height.

Comment: This works in a sense which I am thankful for, but this method causes the whole page to move down when the submenu 'opens'.

Comment: Make the entire nav `position:absolute; `

Comment: This causes the whole navbar to float and also messes up some of my other css/javascript. I appreciate the effort, however I don't think this is quite the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: You'd need to set the parent to `position:relative;` and then adjust the margin for content below.  But if you want to give up now, go ahead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by adjust the margin for content below, could you explain?